# Make the Android text selection float

Tags: android, keyboard, copy, clipboard, paste

I have an app with a EditText in the bottom of the screen 
when im writing into this editText the keyboard opens and covers half of the screen so i see only the bottom half of my screen(so far so good cause the editText is in this half)

now when i press the text the android text selection menu opens up in the top of the screen so 
no i see only the top half of the screen and i cant see my EditText

can i change the selection tool or make it float or change the position of it?

Answer (score 0):

Include these two lines in your edittext layout file.

```
android:freezesText="true"
android:gravity="top"
```

Comment: No it didnt worked. the android text Selection still opens on the top and the softkeyboard block the bottome half of the screen where my EditText is.